# IncorrectCredentialsException after administrator changes user password

Tags: java, spring, shiro

I'm just starting with Apache Shiro, since I "inherited" some code which has the following bug, so bear with me please.

When the administrator changes the password of a user, that user cannot login.
Entering the newly changed password returns an IncorrectCredentialsException. Checking the database, the password has been changed.

The weird thing is that if you enter the old password, you can login. After loging out, you can use your new password.

- The application is Java, built on the Vaadin 8 framework.
- Persistence is used to connect to the MySQL database

There is no shiro.ini file, all I can find is a `security.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/#!login"/>
        <property name="successUrl" value="/"/>
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
                /favicon.ico = noSessionCreation, anon
                /login/ = authc
                /logout/ = logout
                /** = anon
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="realm" ref="myRealm"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myRealm" class="com.example.project.ui.view.panels.login.MyAuthRealm">
    </bean>

    <bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- Enable Shiro Annotations for Spring-configured beans.  Only run after -->
    <!-- the lifecycleBeanProcessor has run: -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"
          depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And a `web.xml` with some filters:

```xml
...
<!-- Apache Shiro -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
...
```

From what I can understand, the default implementation of Shiro has been used and nothing custom has been extended, for example for sessions or cache.

This is the login button listener

```java
loginButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
        boolean isFormValid = true;
        if (isFormValid) {
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken((String) usernameField.getValue(), (String) passField.getValue());
            Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
            try {
                currentUser.login(token);
                Page.getCurrent().reload();
                
            } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
                errorLabel.setValue("Unknown Account. Please try again");
            } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ice) {
                errorLabel.setValue("Incorrect Credentials. Please try again");
            } catch (LockedAccountException lae) {
                errorLabel.setValue("This account is locked");
            } catch (ExcessiveAttemptsException eae) {
                errorLabel.setValue("Too many login attempts. Please try again later");
            } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
                errorLabel.setValue("Something went wrong. Please try again later");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And this is the the doGetAuthenticationInfo from the custom Realm, `MyAuthRealm`

```java
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authcToken)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordToken token = (UsernamePasswordToken) authcToken;
    //  Problem is located here.
    //  For some reason this query returns the old password
    List<AdminUser> results = this.em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM AdminUser u WHERE u.username ='" + token.getPrincipal() + "' AND u.isActive = TRUE").getResultList();
    if (results.size() == 1) {
        SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(((AdminUser) results.get(0)).getUsername(), ((AdminUser) results.get(0)).getPassword(), getName());
        return info;
    }
    return null;
}
```

As I mention in the comments above the `results` variable, for some reason, the query return the password before the administrator changed it and that's why I get the IncorrectCredentialsException.

This is the `AdminUser` model Class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "admin_user")
@Cacheable(false)
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a WHERE a.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findByEmail", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a WHERE a.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findByFistName", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a WHERE a.fistName = :fistName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findByLastName", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a WHERE a.lastName = :lastName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findByLoginAttempts", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a WHERE a.loginAttempts = :loginAttempts"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findByPassword", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a WHERE a.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findByUsername", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a WHERE a.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdminUser.findByRoles", query = "SELECT a FROM AdminUser a WHERE a.roles = :roles")})
public class AdminUser implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "fist_name")
    private String fistName;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "login_attempts")
    private int loginAttempts;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "roles")
    private String roles;
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "settings")
    private String settings;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "adminUserId")
    private Collection<Staff> staffCollection;

    public AdminUser() {
    }

    public AdminUser(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AdminUser(Integer id, String email, int loginAttempts, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.loginAttempts = loginAttempts;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFistName() {
        return fistName;
    }

    public void setFistName(String fistName) {
        this.fistName = fistName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getLoginAttempts() {
        return loginAttempts;
    }

    public void setLoginAttempts(int loginAttempts) {
        this.loginAttempts = loginAttempts;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }

    public void setSettings(String settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public boolean isIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Staff> getStaffCollection() {
        return staffCollection;
    }

    public void setStaffCollection(Collection<Staff> staffCollection) {
        this.staffCollection = staffCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof AdminUser)) {
            return false;
        }
        AdminUser other = (AdminUser) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.model.AdminUser[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea about what might be going one, so you could steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a cache involved, and you need to invalidate the cache of a given realm when you update the user’s password  (or disable caching)

Comment: I've went over the code during execution and it doesn't have caching enabled for the Authentication. The ```getAvailableAuthenticationCache``` method, from the ```AuthenticationRealm``` class, always returns null.

Comment: Step through your realm and see if your what your query is returning.  Also, your have a potential injection issue in your query. Use a prepared statement.